# Simple question: POST or GET, regarding image upload?

Tags: javascript, http, flask, post, get

In my backend API, I return information based on an image that a user uploads; ie. the user "gets" data depending on the image they inputted. Should this be a GET request or a POST request?

I was thinking it should be a GET request, but my code only seems to work if it's a POST request (specifically, the backend server only seems to get the inputted image if the request is a POST request).

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a response from a POST request. The user's is submitting a photo...which generally would be done via POST.  What you return is a response to the user's POST.

Comment: You can't upload an image in a `GET`, it doesn't have a body. Files and images have to be sent in a POST with `Content-type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: @devlincarnate what if the user were to get information based on a text input then? would this be a GET request or a POST request?

Comment: @Edward - it depends. Is the text input sensitive data or a large amount? If yes then send it as a POST in the request body. If you're comfortable with the text being sent in the URL parameters then you could use GET.

Answer (score 1):

Use POST Method only to upload files.
GET won't work as it doesn't have body to pass on values/files